# What is the ど in やけど?

Tags: words, etymology

Given that やけど means "burn", it seems likely that the やけ part is 焼け. What about the ど, though?

(The kanji for やけど - i.e. 火傷 - don't help, because those characters are obviously 当て字, and would ordinarily be read かしょう.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten Dictionary* backs up senshin's answer, listing the following for the term's etymology:

> 「焼け処（ど）」の意。「やけと」とも
>     Meaning 焼{や}け処{ど} ("burnt place").  Also read as *yaketo*

Answer (score 5):

It looks like やけど derives from 焼け + 処, i.e. "burnt place", and was sometimes also written 焼（け）所. cf. [語源由来辞典](http://gogen-allguide.com/ya/yakedo.html):

> やけどを漢字で「火傷」と表記するのは、意味からの当て字。
>   やけどの「やけ」は「焼け」、「ど」は「所」「場所」などを意味する「処」で、「焼け処」が語源である。
>   井原西鶴の浮世草子『好色二代男』に「脇腹を見たまへば、焼所ありありと」とある。